# An augmented matrix which can be consistent or inconsistent, depending upon if the constant matrix is "flipped" or not.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a simple example of a system of equations where the coefficient matrix A (whose entries are written as $a_{ij}$) is such that the augmented matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & ... & a_{1n} & | & 1 \\
    a_{21} & ... & a_{2n} & | & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
is inconsistent, but the augmented matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & ... & a_{1n} & | & 0 \\
    a_{21} & ... & a_{2n} & | & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
is consistent.

I suspect there is a simple example for $n=2$ or $n=3$, but I am at a bit of a loss. Could someone suggest some hints that may push me in the right direction? Or even suggest a systematic way to construct such an example? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the constant matrix have to be 1 and 0, or can it have any values?

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Comment: According to the question, the constant matrix does have to be 1 and 0. But thank you for pointing out that useful theorem! @Tyberius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example is
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr
            1 & 0\cr}$$

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I was too focused on obtaining a matrix with more nonzero entries that I missed that simple example. Thank you!